# How to get the binding root node from a viewmodel to use jQuery.blockUI on it while AJAX posting?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jquery-blockui

I have a DIV, which I use as a binding root node when applying ko bindings this way:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('myContainerDiv'));
```

I have a generic `post` method defined for every viewmodel type, with common ajax handling, etc. In this method I would like to access the binding root node, so in this case the DIV with 'myContainerDiv', for example to be able to use some loading spinner on it or so.

I've checked the documentation but only found the "inverse" operation (`ko.dataFor`). What I would like is something like this pseudo code:

```
BaseViewModel.prototype.post = function(url, options) {
    // this refers to my actual viewmodel

    var element = ....... get the binding root node for 'this'
    element.showLoading();
    ....
    // ajax stuff
    .... 
    element.hideLoading();
};
```

EDIT: I'm using the jQuery.blockUI plugin for showing/hiding loading panels above elements, so it's not just about binding a loading DIV's visible property to an observable.

Comment: Why not just use a boolean observable in your viewmodel and bind it using the "visible" binding to control the visibility of your loading message/status? Separating your view model from the DOM is one of the key goals (IMO) of Knockout.

Comment: I wouldn't like to place a loading panel into every DIV where I have an AJAX updatable viewmodel bound. But anyway I like the idea, I will try to experiment with some custom binding on the container DIV. Also, I'm using the jQuery.blockUI plugin for loading panels, so it's not just about visiblity.

Comment: isnt there $root ? or  element = $parents[$parents.length - 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement a custom binding for the jQuery.blockUI plugin, and bound my container DIV with that to my model's IsLoading property. During the AJAX callback I set the IsLoading observable to true.

```
<div data-bind="blockUI: IsLoading">
    ...
</div>
```

And the binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.blockUI = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value)
            $(element).block();
        else 
            $(element).unblock();
    }
};
```

Thank you for the base idea.